# Create factor based on matching rows from dataframes of unequal size

Tags: r

I have two dataframes

```
DF1   
10
11
12
13
15
16
17
19
```

and

```
DF2
    12
    16
    19
```

I am looking for a way to get an output as

```
DF3
    10 0
    11 0
    12 1
    13 0
    15 0
    16 1
    17 0
    19 1
```

I know how to find matched rows from two data frames

```
match = which(DF1 %in% DF2)
```

but lost in find the way to assign 0/1 for matched rows in these two dataframes. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: If that is a data frame, then it should have a column name. Using `DF1` would not be sufficient.

Comment: Try with `as.integer(DF1[,1] %in% DF2[,1])`

Comment: Maybe `DF3 <- cbind(DF1, data.frame(matched = as.numeric(DF1[, 1] %in% DF2[, 1])))` ?

Comment: @akrun thank you! it worked, could you please make as answer so that i can vote for it? :)

Comment: @ThePooh Thanks, I posted my comment as a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this with `%in%` to create a logical vector, which can be coerced to binary with `as.integer`

```
DF3 <- DF1
DF3$newCol <- as.integer(DF3[,1] %in% DF2[,1])
DF3$newCol
#[1] 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1
```

If we need consecutive numbers from the above result

```
DF3$newCol[DF3$newCol!=0] <- seq_along(DF3$newCol[DF3$newCol!=0])
DF3$newCol
#[1] 0 0 1 0 0 2 0 3
```

Or another option is

```
cumsum(DF1[,1] %in% DF2[,1])*(DF1[,1] %in% DF2[,1])
#[1] 0 0 1 0 0 2 0 3
```

Comment: Sorry is it possible to assign consecutive numbers in 'DF3$newCol' instead of 1 for each matched rows?

Comment: Try `DF3$newCol[DF3$newCol!=0] <- seq_along(DF3$newCol[DF3$newCol!=0])`

Answer (score 0):

This is a good job for `match`:

```
df3 <- df1
df3$matchCol <- +!is.na(match(df1[,1], df2[,1]))

#  df1 matchCol
#1  10        0
#2  11        0
#3  12        1
#4  13        0
#5  15        0
#6  16        1
#7  17        0
#8  19        1
```